# script which will make if else statement, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

Is there any script in jQuery which creates if else statements? Only my variables in the if else statement changes? I was reading something about it a while ago, but i really don´t know how it works.

```
$('input[type="number"]').change(function () {
    var arr = [];
    var arr2 = [];
    i = 0;
    var qtyVal = $('.btm-quantity').val();

    if (qtyVal > arr2[1] < arr2[2]) {
        var celkom = qtyVal * arr[1];
        var celkomR = celkom.toFixed(2);
    } 
    else if (qtyVal > arr2[2] && qtyVal < arr2[3]) {
        var celkom2 = qtyVal * arr[2];
        var celkom2R = celkom2.toFixed(2);
    } 
    else if (qtyVal > arr2[3] && qtyVal < arr2[4]) {
        var celkom3 = qtyVal * arr[3];
        var celkom3R = celkom3.toFixed(2);
    } 
    else if (qtyVal > arr2[4]) {
        var celkom4 = qtyVal * arr[4];
        var celkom4R = celkom4.toFixed(2);
    }
});
```

As you may see else if are the same except last one. What can i do?

Comment: `qtyVal > arr2[1] < arr2[2]` probably won't do what you think it does. Looks like you could probably rewrite this a `for` loop over `arr2`, but this sample seems to be incomplete. What are you doing with the `celkomX` variables?

Comment: you can look here for all code : http://jsfiddle.net/s7b18r6c/5/
and celkomX variables are rounded for 2 decimal places

Comment: You may wish to try either `<=` or `>=`.  Because currently, if `qtyVal` was equal in value to arr2[3] for example (or any others), nothing would actually happen.

Comment: @ne1410s thanks for tip, i will try this, cause my default code is not working

Comment: currently, i really dont know how can i rewrite this to for...

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[type='number']").change(function() {
  var celkom, qtyVal;
  qtyVal = parseFloat($(".btm-quantity").val());
  switch(true) {
    case (qtyVal >= kolvo[0] && qtyVal < kolvo[1]): celkom = cena[0]; break;
    case (qtyVal >= kolvo[1] && qtyVal < kolvo[2]): celkom = cena[1]; break;
    case (qtyVal >= kolvo[2] && qtyVal < kolvo[3]): celkom = cena[2]; break;
    case ((qtyVal >= kolvo[3]) && (qtyVal < kolvo[4])): celkom = cena[3]; console.log('cena3', kolvo[3]); break;
    case (qtyVal >= kolvo[4]): celkom = cena[4]; break;
  }
    console.log(celkom);
  $(".celkom").html((qtyVal*celkom).toFixed(2));   
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s7b18r6c/11/